# I want to search posts on basis of tags in Laravel 8

Tags: json, laravel, search, tags, posts

I have stored tags of posts in a database like

```
["trending","toppost","tags"]
```

and I need to create an API to find posts on basis of tags search

In Postman, I use to send data like this

```
{
    "tag":["trending","chindhawali"]
}
```

and if any post has one of these tags (its not necessary to match all tags)
that I need to sort out.

So how can I do this in Laravel 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereHas() if you set up a relationship

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships